# Can I still get charged for data if I dont use my sim card?

Tags: cellular-data, sim

First of all my broadband is orange and it doesn't tell you when it's gone over the mb so I pay around £20 a month and the end of last month it came up to £65 so mostly I use the phone at work and at home so I thought that if I took out the sim and use the wifi, would I still get charged for that if I took out the sim?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a contract, the fixed monthly fees will still apply (if you use it or not) with SIM installed or not.

If you do not use your mobile data (true your carrier) but use free WiFi, you will not be charged any fees for that by your carrier..

You can always go into your Cellular settings to turn off data which will allow for you to receive phone calls and text without the use of data.